# How install codeblocks 17.12.1 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, code-blocks

I have downloaded `codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz` and extracted it. But it creates a no `.deb` folder consist of many `.deb` files. I remember in previous version there was only one `.deb` file I could install it by `dpkg -i x.deb` command.

But how about this?

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal in extracted directory and try these:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./*
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt --purge autoremove
```

and you can see CodeBlocks in your installed applications.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to install it as Debian .deb binary package.

For downloading, follow instructions from [here (semiofficial code clocks binaries)](https://%20https://apt.jenslody.de/)

Read on how to install a .deb package for example here:

- [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Alternatively, you could build code::blocks from source which would probably preferrable if you feel comfortable building applications from source, or use a fedora/red-hat package. These possibilities are from [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this command and it worked:

```
sudo dpkg -i codeblocks-common_17.12-1_all.deb codeblocks-contrib-common_17.12-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1:

```
sudo dpkg -i codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64.deb codeblocks-common_17.12-1_all.deb libcodeblocks0_17.12-1_amd64.deb
```